# How to handle [Errno -2] in paramiko?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, server, paramiko

I have script to login to multiple servers and take output. During login, a few servers throw this error:

> "[Errno -2] Name or service not known"

This causes the script to break in middle. How can I handle this exception? I have used try/except already but it didn't seem to work:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ip  = open("files.txt","r")
data = ip.readlines()
try:
  for ips in data:
  ips = ips.strip("\n")
  ssh.connect(ips,username='Lock',password='Key',timeout=10)
  chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
  chan.get_pty()
  chan.exec_command("uname -a")
  result =  [chan.recv(1024)]
except Exception as e:
  print e
```

Note: Server names are kept in files.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the script to continue with the next address in the loop, you need to put your try/except inside of the for loop:

```
for ips in data:
    try:
        ips = ips.strip("\n")
        ssh.connect(ips, username='Lock', password='Key', timeout=10)
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```